# Android Universal image loader set background

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm using android universal image loader for loading some image in a gridview. The thing is I want these images to have also a background image,  I mean two images on top of each other, I looked at universal image loader to see if there are any options to set such image but I couldn't find any.
I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks very much

Comment: Why not set a background to your ImageView in the layout？

Comment: `The thing is I want these images to have also a background image, I mean two images on top of each other` this is related to design instead of `universal image loader` so you need to create own layout using FrameLayout and RelativeLayout

Comment: But I already have a grid layout